# Not able to get String value from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I save some String data to SharedPreferences but unfortunately i am unable to get the string value from sharedPreferences.

This is my code to save the data to SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(Config.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
userPhone = etPhone.getText().toString();
prefs.edit().putString("userPhone", userPhone).apply();
```

This saves my number perfectly but when i try to retrieve it in the next activity i get this string instead "userPhone"

This is how i retrieve the string value

```
String phoneNumber = prefs.getString(Config.PREF_NAME, "userPhone");
Log.i("number", phoneNumber);
```

My logs show **phoneNumber** as a string instead of the value from the user input that i saved to sharedPrefrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For storing values into `SharedPreferences` you are using `Editor` and method call:

```
prefs.edit().putString(String key, String value)
```

And you did it right:

```
prefs.edit().putString("userPhone", userPhone).apply();
```

For retrieving data, we are using the same key as we used for storing. In your case, it is "userPhone".
So, you should do it with:

```
prefs.getString("userPhone", "Some default value");
```

But, you mixed key with preferences name and you called

```
prefs.getString(Config.PREF_NAME, "userPhone");
```

Comment: You should add an explanation as to where he went wrong, rather than posting code and hoping it is understood.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference.
You are actually retrieving the value from:

```
String phoneNumber = prefs.getString(Config.PREF_NAME, "userPhone");
```

But you need to do :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String phoneNumber = sharedPreferences.getString("userPhone", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this in your second Activity.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(Config.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String phoneNumber = prefs.getString("userPhone", "defaultValueIfNoPhoneAvailable");
Log.i("number", phoneNumber);
```

The second parameter of `getString` is the default value in case it has no mapping for the key.